# Error raised while trying to run code with pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to run a code with pyaudio but some errors occured

```
# import library

import speech_recognition as sr
# Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)

r = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Microphone as source
# listening the speech and store in audio_text variable

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Talk")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("Time over, thanks")
    # recoginize_() method will throw a request error if the API is unreachable, hence using exception handling

    try:
        # using google speech recognition
        print("Text: " + r.recognize_google(audio_text))
    except:
        print("Sorry, I did not get that")
```

The errors are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\hello_world.py", line 11, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I have installed pyaudio manually with `pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39m-win_amd64.whl` and also did `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python`.

I tried also to install into pycharm the pyaudio but also an error raised.

```
C:\Users>pip freeze
comtypes==1.1.9
PyAudio @ file:///C:/Users/Downloads/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl


C:\Users>python -m pip install pyaudio
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (0.2.11)
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the virtual environment where you run your app, is the *same* environment where you installed pyaudio. The Traceback shows it's looking for pyaudio in "*C:\Users\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages...*" but you installed it in "*c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages*"

Comment: @GinoMempin I uninstall the module and install it again in the virtuenv that the pycharm was searching and it worked. So the point was to install it inside the project's env.

Answer (score 1):

you are using **virtual environment** and I guess you've installed the library for the **primary virtual environment**. you can fix this by recreating the **virtual environment**

[**Edited**]

as you can see,  in your output for `python -m pip install pyaudio` you are using the primary one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pip install with the full path tothe .whl file?

```
pip install C:/Users/Downloads/PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

Make sure you use are using python 3.9 if you install cp39. I noticed you are referring to both cp37 and cp39 versions in your question.

Comment: Yes I have tried this